# Div class="jumbotron" to scale to size of its background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have image of size 1400x560 and I want the my `jumbotron` div to scale to fit the size of the image. It works fine when i set the width of the jumbotron to that of the image but when I shrink the website to mobile view, I have issues. So how can I fix this?
*I forgot to mention i have issue with the height and not the width, The jumbotron scales div to the width of 1400 but not to the height 560px*
Here is a preview of the html page http://threeguys.us/rts/testing.html.

When i shrink the page , i want the image to resize according to the width of the browser

**index.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.jumbotron
{   
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
background-image:url('images/car/car.jpg');
background-size: cover;
height:560px;
 }
```

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: I don't believe the height is affected by mobile view.  The height just changes how much you can scroll.  If you need your div to have a certain height, fill it with content or define it in pixels.  Set `width: 100%;` so it can scale.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: preview the link i updated above , I want the image to shrink when viewing in mobile view

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in my answer?

Comment: Yea i did , i only have issues with height not with the width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`background: contain;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).  Simply add this to your class as follows:

```
.jumbotron
{   
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    background-image:url('images/car/car.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background: contain;
    width: 100%; /* make sure to define width to fill container */
    height: 100px; /* define the height in pixels or make sure   */
                   /* you have something in your div with height */
                   /* so you can see your image */
    max-width:1400px;  /* define the max width */
 }
```

The background image will now scale with the size of the `div` (assuming the `div` is scalable).  If you want to constrain your `div` so it does not get bigger than a certain size (in your case, the size of the background image), use [`max-width: 1400px;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

See my [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wGRD7/2257/).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to get the `div` to fit the size of its background image, so I suggest you use an `img` tag instead.

To get your `div` to fit the size of the image, use `display: inline-block` on the div:

```css
.jumbotron
{   
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid red 1px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background-size: 100%;
width:100%
position:relative;
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `jumbotron` with:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

It should make it fit width-wise to the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple. Thanks

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/sky-wallpapers-28043-8362242.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
```